# Function of an operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, mathematics

Every linear bounded self-adjoint operator $T : {\scr H} \to {\scr H} $can be written in terms of its eigenvalues and their associated projectors (see [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Spectral_theorem)):  $$ T = \sum_{{\frak spec}(T) }\lambda \ P_\lambda$$

For finite-dimensional spaces, there's an equivalent matrix formulation:

> Every hermitian matrix is similar to a diagonal one via unitary transformations.

In this context, we can also consider "functions of operators":
$$f(T) = \sum_{{\frak spec}(T)} f(\lambda) P_\lambda$$

It's simply the function acting on each of its eigenvalues.
But what about a "Taylor expansion"?

What does it mean $$f(T) = \sum _n \frac {f^{(n)} (0)}{n!} T^n?$$

Comment: Maybe writing it down helps, because the answer is almost there with your second formula. Note that $P^2_\lambda = P_\lambda$ since it is a projection operator. Rest you can fill in.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Tip: Try an exponential of a matrix, and then an operator. I assume you get it about [Syvester's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider,
$$
T=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma\left(T\right)}\lambda P_{\lambda}
$$
and,
$$
P_{\lambda}P_{\lambda'}=\delta\left(\lambda,\lambda'\right)P_{\lambda}$$
Do the expansion and you'll see immediately that,
$$
f\left(T\right)=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma\left(T\right)}f\left(\lambda\right)P_{\lambda}
$$

Comment: Made one mistake that I think you spotted immediately: $P_{\lambda}P_{\lambda'}=\delta\left(\lambda,\lambda'\right)P_{\lambda}$. Edited and corrected omission.